# sequelize one-to-one and one-to-many association between same tables

Tags: sequelize.js, one-to-many, one-to-one

Let's say I have a `CashRegister` model and `Transaction` model.
It's obvious that a `CashRegiser.hasMany(Transaction)`.
However, what if I need to save the last `transactionId` for quick access on the `CashRegister` table? Now I need to implement both `CashRegiser.hasMany(Transaction)` and `CashRegiser.hasOne(Transaction) // as lastTransactionId`.
How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to indicate a foreign key and to distinguish associations then use the `as` and `foreignKey`option like this:

```js
CashRegiser.hasMany(Transaction, { as: 'transactions' })
CashRegiser.hasOne(Transaction, { foreignKey: 'lastTransactionId', as: 'lastTransaction' })
```

Comment: Tried something like this:
```javascript
CashRegiser.hasOne(Transaction, { sourceKey: 'lastTransactionId', targetKey: 'id', as: 'lastTransaction' });
CashRegiser.hasMany(Transaction, { sourceKey: 'id', targetKey: 'cash_register_id', as: 'transactions' });
```
but then i see in logs
```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "transactions" AS "lastTransaction"
                    ON "cash_registers"."last_transaction_id" = "lastTransaction"."last_transaction_id"
```
Not sure why it picks the wrong field for the the join ("lastTransaction"."last_transaction_id" should have been "lastTransaction"."id")

Comment: `hasOne` does not have `targetKey` option, only `sourceKey` (should be equal to `id` in your case) and `foreignKey` (should be equal to `transactionId` in your case). The same goes for `hasMany`: `sourceKey: 'id'`, `foreignKey: 'cash_register_id'`